# Как делить входной список целых чисел на два списка с одинаковыми суммами элементов?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, list

```
def equal_parts(numbers):
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    numbers.sort(reserve = True)
    for i in numbers:
        if sum(lst1) < sum(lst2):
            lst1.append(i)
        else:
            lst2.append(i)
    return lst1
    return lst2

'''
list(int) ->  list(int), list(int)
Return two integers list of equal sum as
an attempt at a partition of input numbers
equal_parts([2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 23, 1, 1, 34])
([23, 13, 7, 6, 4, 1]),([34, 12, 5, 2, 1])

'''
```

Как делить входной список целых чисел на два списка с одинаковыми суммами элементов ???
Непонимаю в чем проблема ...
Помогите плз))

Comment: похожий вопрос: [divide an array into two sets with minimal difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6597180/4279)

Comment: Пожалуйста, перестаньте вандализировать свои собственные вопросы - это противоречит правилам сайта. За это могут и забанить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вы делаете, делать нельзя. Вы пытаетесь жадно добавлять элементы в меньший список (кстати сумму лучше поддерживать самому, а не перевычмслять каждый раз). Простейший пример: 5 4 3 3 3. Вы положите вашим способом 5 и 4 в разные списки, и дальше ничего не выйдет.

Эта классическая задача о рюкзаке. Она решается либо с помощью динамического программирования (элементы разумно небольшие, сумма до миллиона-10 например) либо с помощью какого-нибудь метода ветвей и границ (количество элементов в пределах 20-30). В остальных случаях за разумное время/память вы её не решите.

Вам нужно сначала вычислить сумму всего списка, потом псевдокод такой (ДП, полный перебор сами напишите). Предполагаю что только положительные элементы, если есть отрицательные то нужно пару модификаций сделать.

```
массив предыдущий инициализировать -1
предыдущий[0] = 0
цикл по списку
   val - текущий элемент списка
   цикл i от суммы списка/2 до val
      если предыдущий[i] = -1 и предыдущий[i-val] != -1 
      то предыдущий[i] = val


//получение ответа
Если предыдущий[sum/2] = -1 то выйти
Текущий = sum/2
Пока текущий != 0
    Вывести предыдущий[текущий]
    текущий = текущий - предыдущий[текущий]
```

Пример реализации:

```
def gen_left(numbers):
    K = sum(numbers)
    prev = [-1] * (K // 2 + 1)
    prev[0] = 0
    for val in numbers:
        for i in range(K // 2, val-1, -1): # K//2..val inclusive
            if prev[i] == -1 and prev[i - val] != -1:
                prev[i] = val
    if prev[K//2] == -1:
        raise ValueError
    curr = K // 2
    while curr > 0:
        yield prev[curr]
        curr -= prev[curr]

def partition_equal_sums(numbers):
    left = list(gen_left(numbers))
    right = list(numbers)
    for item in left: # O(n**2)
        right.remove(item)
    if sum(right) != sum(left):
        raise ValueError
    return left, right
```

Comment: @jfs это 1 список. Во 2 все остальные пойдут.

Comment: @jfs да, спасибо) правда удаление за квадрат некрасиво чуть, но это непринципиально уже.

Comment: чтобы не `O(n**2)`, нужно просто индексы вместо значений сохранять (как в моём ответе с `p(i,j)`). Я оставил как есть, чтобы от вашего текста описания алгоритма не отклоняться.

Comment: @jfs забирайте в свой ответ этот алгоритм, да я этот ответ удалю. Чтобы полный ответ вышел) жадник перебор и ДП

Comment: я не очень хорошо понимаю как он работает (я его просто в лоб один в один по описанию реализовал и он простые тесты проходит). Похож на [это описание](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5898540/4279), но я не уверен. Вообще я отдельными ответами разные алгоритмы не публиковал, только чтобы обозначения и нарастающую сложность смягчить. А в целом удобней и голосовать и комментировать разные варианты в разных ответах.

Answer (score 1):

Задача: можно ли разбить набор положительных целых чисел на две части с равными суммами—это задача о разбиении ([partition problem/number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)), которая является [NP-полной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0). NP класс значит, что быстрые алгоритмы решения не известны, но если решение найдено, то можно быстро проверить верно ли оно. Хотя на практике, решение может быть найдено быстро для небольших чисел—[это самая лёгкая из тяжёлых/сложных задач](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/id.3278,y.0,no.,content.true,page.99999,css.print/issue.aspx).

Это частный случай [задачи о сумме подмножеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2), которую в свою очередь [можно рассматривать как некоторый специальный случай задачи о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5).

Ответ содержит три решения:

- Жадный алгоритм (не всегда работает)
- Метод грубой силы—полный перебор (O(n 2<sup>n</sup>))
- Решение с помощью динамического программирования с псевдополиномиальным временем (O(n k))

### Жадный алгоритм (не всегда работает)

Код в вопросе реализует жадный алгоритм: взять самое большое число из ещё невыбранных и добавить к части, у которой сейчас сумма меньше:

```
def partition_equal_sums_greedy(numbers):
    parts, sums = ([], []), [0, 0]
    for largest in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
        smaller = sums[1] < sums[0]
        parts[smaller].append(largest)
        sums[smaller] += largest
    if sums[0] != sums[1]:
        raise ValueError("Greedy algorithm has failed to find the"
                         " number partitioning for {numbers!r}".format(**vars()))
    return parts
```

Чтобы найти решение для примера в вопросе, достаточно

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT
return lst1
return lst2
```

заменить на:

```
return lst1, lst2
```

Пример:

```
>>> partition_equal_sums([2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 23, 1, 1, 34])
([34, 12, 5, 2, 1], [23, 13, 7, 6, 4, 1])
```

Это простой быстрый алгоритм, но как [@pavel указал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587774/23044), жадный алгоритм не всегда работает для данной задачи: для `[5, 4, 3, 3, 3]` он возвращает: `([5, 3], [4, 3, 3])` части, которые имеют неравные суммы.

Вот ещё пример [из ссылки выше](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/id.3278,y.0,no.,content.true,page.99999,css.print/issue.aspx), для которого жадный алгоритм не работает:

```
771 121 281 854 885 734 486 1003 83 62
```

В общем случае, чтобы найти решение для `n` чисел может понадобиться порядка 2<sup>n</sup> шагов (когда величина чисел порядка 2<sup>n</sup>). Для сравнения: если наибольшее число во вводе не зависит от `n`, тогда жадный алгоритм является линейным—`O(n)` (при использовании O(n) сортировки).

Чтобы почувствовать разницу: для `n = 1000`, линейный алгоритм требует порядка `1000` шагов, в то время как 2<sup>1000</sup> равно 
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376.

Эта причина, по которой задачи из NP класса считаются тяжёлыми/сложными (если [NP!=P](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_P_%D0%B8_NP), то экспоненциальное решение—это лучшее на что можно надеяться в общем случае, если не рассматривать недетерминистические решения).

### Метод грубой силы—полный перебор

Вот решение полным перебором всех вариантов разбиения входного списка на две части и проверки имеют ли эти части равные суммы:

```
from itertools import compress, product

def partition_equal_sums_brute_force(numbers):
    if sum(numbers) % 2 == 0: # even sum
        for selectors in product([0, 1], repeat=len(numbers)):
            if sum(compress(numbers, selectors)) == sum(numbers) // 2:
                return (list(compress(numbers, selectors)),
                        list(compress(numbers, (not s for s in selectors))))
    raise ValueError("Can't partition into two parts with equal sums"
                     " for {numbers!r}".format(**vars()))
```

[`product([0, 1], repeat=len(numbers))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) просто все двоичные числа длиной `len(numbers)` генерирует, например, для `len(numbers) == 3`: 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 (предствленные как список `0`,`1` цифр). [`compress(numbers, selectors)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) возвращает те числа из `numbers`, на тех местах где стоят единички (`1`) в `selectors`.

Это `O(n*2**n)` алгоритм, который можно улучшить до `O(2**n)`, если не перевычислять каждый раз сумму заново для частей.

Пример:

```
>>> partition_equal_sums([2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 23, 1, 1, 34])
([7, 13, 34], [2, 4, 5, 6, 12, 23, 1, 1])
>>> partition_equal_sums([5, 4, 3, 3, 3])
([3, 3, 3], [5, 4])
>>> partition_equal_sums([771, 121, 281, 854, 885, 734, 486, 1003, 83, 62])
([121, 885, 486, 1003, 83, 62], [771, 281, 854, 734])
```

Не смотря на то, что для произвольного ввода в худшем случае может потребоваться экспоненциальное время (детерминистический случай), чтобы найти решение для всех известных алгоритмов для этой задачи, но на практике для многих вводов решение может быть найдено гораздо быстрее.

### Решение с помощью динамического программирования с псевдополиномиальным временем

Легко узнать можно ли разбить заданный набор чисел на две части с равными суммами, если сумма невелика:

```
import functools

def can_partition(numbers):
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def p(s, j):
        return p(s, j - 1) or p(s - numbers[j - 1], j - 1) if j else (s == 0)
    n = len(numbers)
    s, odd = divmod(sum(numbers), 2)
    return not odd and p(s, n)
```

где `p(s, j)` истинно, если cумма некоторого подмножества `numbers[:j]` равна `s`. `p(s, n)` говорит существует ли подмножество `numbers` с суммой равной `s`. Что для чётного общей суммы это означает, что можно разбить `numbers` на две части с равными суммами.

Это реализация на Питоне [`O(k n)` алгоритма для задачи разбиения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm), который является частным случаем
[алгоритма для суммы подмножеств (на русском)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.89.D1.8C.D1.8E_.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.BC_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BC).

Пример:

```
>>> can_partition([1, 2])
False
>>> can_partition([1, 2, 3])
True
```

Чтобы искомые два списка получить из `p(s, j)`:

```
def partition_equal_sums(numbers):
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def p(s, j):
        return p(s, j - 1) or p(s - numbers[j - 1], j - 1) if j else (s == 0)
    j = len(numbers)
    s, odd = divmod(sum(numbers), 2)
    if odd or not p(s, j):
        raise ValueError("Can't partition into two parts with equal sums"
                         " for {numbers!r}".format(**vars()))

    left, right = [], []
    while s:
        while p(s, j):  # sum(some_subset(numbers[:j])) == s
            j -= 1
            right.append(numbers[j])
        s -= right[-1]  # sum(some_subset(numbers[:j])) == s - numbers[j]
        left.append(right.pop())
    return left, numbers[:j] + right
```

[`functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) кэширует возвращаемые значения `p(s,j)`, что позволяет получить `O(N K)` (псевдополиномиальный) алгоритм. Используя `p(s,j)`, он ищет такой индекс `j`, что:

```
sum(some_subset(numbers[:j+1])) == s
sum(some_subset(numbers[:j])) != s
```

то есть без `numbers[j]` элемента, предыдущие числа (индекс `<j`) сумму `s`  не могут набрать. Поэтому `numbers[j]` выбирается как слагаемое и цикл повторяется для `s - numbers[j]` суммы, пока оставшаяся сумма не равна нулю. По построению, `sum(left) == sum(numbers) // 2` и так как этот код исполняется только для чётной общей суммы (`sum(numbers) % 2 == 0`), то `sum(right) == sum(numbers) // 2` и решение найдено (`right` содержит все элементы из `numbers`, которые не в `left` списке и `sum(left) == sum(right)`).

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить метод полного перебора всех возможных комбинаций:

```
def next_indexes_set(indexes, numCount):
    count = len(indexes)
    for reverseIndex in range(1, count + 1):
        if indexes[-reverseIndex] < (numCount - reverseIndex):
            indexes[-reverseIndex] += 1
            for index in range(count - reverseIndex + 1, count):
                indexes[index] = indexes[index - 1] + 1
            return True
    return False


def split_list(numbers):
    numCount = len(numbers)
    fullSum = sum(numbers)
    searchSum = fullSum // 2

    for count in range(numCount // 2 + 1, 1, -1):
        indexes = [i for i in range(count)]
        while 1:
            curSum = sum([numbers[i] for i in indexes])
            if curSum == searchSum:
                indexes.sort(reverse=True)
                listA = [numbers[i] for i in indexes]
                listB = numbers[:]
                for i in indexes:
                    del listB[i]
                return listA, listB
            if not next_indexes_set(indexes, numCount):
                break
    return None, None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [4,3,1,2,4] * 5
    print(numbers, sum(numbers))
    listA, listB = split_list(numbers)
    if listA:
        print(listA, sum(listA))
        print(listB, sum(listB))
```

Только учтите, что увеличение размера разбиваемого списка очень сильно увеличивает время выполнения.