# Умножение строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть три примера:

1. Пример: `'s' * 3`
   Результат: `'sss'`
2. Пример: `'s' * True`
   Результат: `'s'`
3. Пример: `'s' * 3.7`
   Результат: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Вопросы:

1. Почему *пример 2* возвращает 's'?
2. Почему *пример 3* выбрасывает исключение?

Comment: 1 - скорее всего True == 1 неявное преобразование. 2 - нет умножения на дробное. К целому не приводит напрямую.

Comment: Выходит, что True приводится к 1 типа int? Почему так происходит?

Comment: @Max, потому, что внутреннее представление True == 1, попробуйте: `True * 3.7`

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/

Comment: @vadimvaduxa хорошая статья, но на английском(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С ошибкой в третьем примере всё очевидно - строчку нельзя повторить дробное число раз, поэтому умножение строки определено только на int.

Со вторым примером немножко интереснее.

Разработчики питона не стали делать логический тип с чистого листа, а просто унаследовали его от int. При этом True эквивалентно единице, а False - нулю.

Таким образом, с логическим типом данных можно делать все математические действие, которые определены для целочисленного типа.

```
isinstance(True, int)

# Выведет: True
# То есть логический тип действительно является потомком int

3 + True

# Выведет: 4
# То есть True действительно эквивалентен единице

3 / False

# Выведет ошибку деления на ноль
# То есть False действительно эквивалентно нулю
```

Comment: Как следствие это позволяет условия как индексы использовать, к примеру чтобы [выбрать октант по заданным x,y координатам](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95550/6143): `octant = [([1, 2], [8, 7]), ([4, 3], [5, 6])][x < 0][y < 0][abs(x) < abs(y)]` Обычно одного индекса достаточно e.g., `even_odd[n&1].append(n)`, чтобы четные в один список шли, нечётные в другой. Или в [жадном алгоритме `sums[smaller] += largest` к меньшей сумме позволяет компактно добавлять](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588581/23044)