# Partition problem

Tags: java, алгоритм

Приветствую всех! Есть такая задача: вводится n чисел (1 < n < 1000 , у вводимых чисел тот же диапазон). Нужно разбить числа на два массива с минимальной разницей сумм. Partition problem в общем. Написал код, который перебирает все варианты, он работает правильно, но слишком медленно. Нашел на википедии подобный алгоритм
решения этой задачи:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Ввод чисел
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[] array = new int[n];
        String x;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
        while ((x = reader.readLine()) != null)
            s = s.append(x).append(' ');
        String[] strs = (s.toString().trim().split("\\s+"));
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);

        //собственно сам алгоритм.
        Arrays.sort(array);
        int suma = 0, sumb = 0;
        for (int i = array.length; i > 0;) {
            if (suma < sumb)
                suma += array[--i];
            else
                sumb += array[--i];
        }
        System.out.print(Math.abs(suma - sumb));
    }
}
```

Этот алгоритм работает гораздо быстрее, но временами выдает неправильные ответы на некоторых тестах (тестов у меня нет). Хотелось бы узнать, как решить эту проблему, или как минимум найти вышеупомянутые тесты. Возможно, этот алгоритм правильно работает только при числах, идущих по порядку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587750/Как-делить-входной-список-целых-чисел-на-два-списка-с-одинаковыми-суммами-элемен/587774#587774 тут почти весь ответ. Вам надо только не выйти из функции, если там -1, а найти ближайшую к середине не минус единицу.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался с кодом, осталось дописать, чтобы искало разницу, а не разбивало на две равные части. Только один вопрос остался, что неправильный код делает в Википедии: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm ?

Comment: алгоритм правильный, но там написано ЖАДНЫЙ. Т.е. он не гарантирует точность, зато работает быстро. Иногда это нужнее. `This greedy approach is known to give a  7⁄6-approximation to the optimal solution` т.е. он не больше чем на 17% ошибётся)