# Перебор количества сумм

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Мы имеем вводные данные `M` и `N`, `N > M`, `M > 0`.
После этого мы создаем список от `1` до `M`, а дальше нам надо найти все возможные варианты сумм элементов в списке чтобы сумма элементов равнялась `N`, причём каждый элемент списка можно складывать с самим собой несколько раз.
Надо вывести количество сумм, которое можно сделать в списке.

Например: `M = 3` , `N = 4`, ---> `[1,2,3]` --->  `1+1+1+1`, `1+1+2`, `1+2+1`, `2+1+1`, `2+2`, `1+3`, `3+1`, количество возможных вариантов сумм в этом примере: `7`.

Comment: Вот такие варианты - 1,3 и 3,1 - неочевидны. Элементы одни и те же и одинаковое число раз используются

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как делить входной список целых чисел на два списка с одинаковыми суммами элементов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587750/23044)

Comment: если порядок слагаемых не учитывать: [`C = lambda m, n: sum(C(m-1, n-k*m) for k in range(n//m+1)) if m > 1 and n > 1 else 1`](https://ideone.com/hY0rvh)

Answer (score 1):

Общее количество вариантов можно посчитать, суммируя возможные варианты для каждого допустимого слагаемого по очереди:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def C(m, n):
    return sum(C(m, n - k) for k in range(1, min(m, n) + 1)) if n else 1

print(C(3, 4)) # -> 7
```

[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) используется, чтобы не пересчитывать уже рассмотренные варианты.

Comment: Может, сказалось то, что я не спал всю ночь, но я допирал до этого алгоритма несколько часов. Вы бы добавили объяснение.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия решение в ответе это [адаптация из вопроса с более сложным случаем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588581/23044) (ссылка выше была). Если всё равно не ясно, то можно начать с чтения о динамическом программировании.

Comment: Да я разобрался. Написал же "допирал", значит, в конце концов допёр.)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу `jfs`.

Думается мне, что массивом быстрее.

```py
def C(M, N):
    f = [0] * (N + 1)
    f[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(min(M, i), 0, -1):
            f[i] += f[i - j]     
    return f[N]
```

Comment: если вас производительность интересует, то полезно её измерить. Что-нибудь вроде: [`python -m timeit -s "from array_solution import C" "C(3, 4)"`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775750/23044)

Comment: @jfs проверил через `time.time()`, на больших числах появляется большая разница, на небольших, например, на 16 и 32 у моего метода `0.000187`, у вашего - `0.00138`, если через `python -m timeit -s` у моего пишет `20000000 loops, best of 5: 13.6 nsec per loop`, у вашего - `20000000 loops, best of 5: 13.9 nsec per loop`. Я кроме синтаксиса питона больше практически ничего не знаю, как может какой-то непонятный цикл (loop) выполниться за 14nsec на числах 10 и 100? Там же явно больше времени должно уйти!